# Kotlin: how to get the start time of a day and end time of a day?

Tags: kotlin, date, unix, timestamp, unix-timestamp

My input is unix seconds from epoch, which represents the date, that I need to work with, I need to convert the date to start time of a day and end time of a day of the same date, what are possible options to do so in Kotlin?

Comment: What platform are you on? If you're on the JVM, have you looked at the facilities in the various `java.time.*` packages?

Comment: Do you know which time-zone you're using? The day starts at different times in different time-zones.

Comment: @gidds currently I'm using UTC time zone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `LocalDate` to easily achieve this behaviour using epoch

```
val localDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeInEpoch).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()
val startDate = localDate.atStartOfDay() // (or) localDate.atTime(LocalTime.MIN)
val endDate = localDate.atTime(LocalTime.MAX)
```

Comment: This makes sense if they're on the JVM, but Kotlin also compiles to JavaScript and native binaries.

Comment: The general recommendation is to use the first moment of the following day as end-of-day exclusive. So I’d use `localDate.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay()`. Also the OP said *My input is unix* seconds *from epoch*, so they will need `Instant.ofEpochsecond(timeInEpoch)`.